# PHP- I get errors on this code . The error says , Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q = "SELECT CONCAT" (lname ', ', fname) AS name
DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, %M %d, %Y) AS regdat FROM users
ORDER BY registration_date DESC;        
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon $q);
```

Comment: Did you successfully execute `mysqli_connect`? It seems like `$dbcon` is `null`.

Comment: missing a comma between __$dbcon__ and __ $q__

Comment: You missed the comma. `$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);`

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query ($dbcon $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));` while removing the `@` symbol would have triggered an error which should read as `$result = mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));` - `@` is an error suppressor.

Comment: Put down the `@` and step away from the function. What are you doing?! That's suppressing errors. That really should be called the "YOLO Operator".

Comment: @tadman I like the name :)

Comment: Please get into the habit of [searching for your errors first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+mysqli_query%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli%2C+null+given+in) (this finds 117 possible duplicates). Also, try to stick to a succinct title, and then add at least one sentence in the body of the question. Writing entirely in the title is what people did with email circa 1992 `;-)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have there error in quotes:

```
$q = "SELECT CONCAT(lname, ', ', fname) AS name,
             DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%M %d, %Y') AS regdat 
      FROM users
      ORDER BY registration_date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);
```

Comment: Plus the missing comma for `($dbcon $q)` ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks, I've added there the rest of code. First I wanted to edit just a query :-).